# How to select elements with the same classes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select elements with the same classes and show them so I tried the following:

```
$( $(this).className ).show();
```

But the following

```
console.log( $(this).attr("class") );
```

Gives back `a b c` when the class is `class="a b c"` and I want `a.b.c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the both methods `split()` and `join()` like :

```
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');

$( '.' + classes ).show();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#span-1').on('click', function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');

    $( '.' + classes ).show();
})
```

```css
#span-2,#span-3,#span-4{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="a b c" id="span-1">Span 1 (Click me)</span>
<br>
<span class="a b" id="span-2">Span 2(Hidden)</span>
<span class="a b c" id="span-3">Span 3 with same classes (Hidden)</span>
<span class="b c" id="span-4">Span 4 (Hidden)</span>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer - this one handles multiple classes better.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the spaces with `.`:

```
$('.' + $(this).attr('class').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '.')).show();
```

Comment: `replace` only replace the first match. Unless you're using a Regexp

Answer (score 0):

First you have to `trim` the className, then split it using `\/s*/` as there could be more than one space between the classes and around them. Then you have to handle the empty className:

```
var className = $(this).attr("class");
var classes = className.trim().split(/\s*/);
var selector = classes.length? '.' + classes.join('.'): '*'; //because then all elements have the same class (the empty class)

var $matches = $(selector);
```